# How to get past grub rescue?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

So this weekend when my Windows install crashed I decided to create a partition for Ubuntu for my application development instead of running Ubuntu on a VM. But I didn't install Ubuntu with the right file system I wanted, so I formatted that partition while I was in my install of Windows.

Now I am getting this when I am trying to boot into Windows.

```
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue >
```

What do I need to do to get past this so I can boot into Windows? And where would Ubuntu install the extra files for something to run like this?

I know basic Unix/Linux commands, but not enough to figure out how to get past this.

Answer (score 2):

grub2 consists of 2 stages. the first (small) one lives in a boot-sector and launches the second one, which will do all the fancy stuff, and resides on the `/boot` partition (or lacking that, on the `/` partition of your system).

since you have wiped your entire linux installation, you have also wiped the 2nd stage of grub.

### quick (ad-hoc) solution

you could try switching to the (U)EFI boot menu of your system, and launch w32 directly.
this effectively bypasses `grub`.

usually you should see something like "<kbd>F12</kbd> Boot Menu" which will get you to the (U)EFI boot menu (if such a thing exists on your system).

### a more permanent solution

install the linux-distribution of your choice on the newly formatted partition, without worrying too much about w32.
once the linux system is up and running, you will have a working `grub` again, which you can configure to chainload w32. (chances are high, that it will even detect w32 during installation and automatically add it to the boot menu).

Comment: Thank you for your response. How could I locate the Ubuntu boot loader that is installed on another hard drive? I cannot find it, because I am going to go a different route with my Ubuntu install. And I want to remove grub so I can boot straight into Windows.